# jQuery background image change after search is complete

Tags: jquery, background-image

I'm trying to set an input text image to show a loading gif while my search is running. I have that part all working as intended but I would like when the search is complete to revert back to a checkmark to show the user the search has been completed.  Here is the code I've been working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demoTable').columnFilters({wildCard:"", alternateRowClassNames:['tablerow_odd', 'tablerow_even']});
  $('._filterText').keypress(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image':'url(\'http://frenemylogicians.com/forum/constructore/img/loading.gif\')'});
  });
    $('._filterText').css({'background-image':'url(\'http://frenemylogicians.com/forum/constructore/img/tick.png\')'});
});
```

Just to hopefully clarify things of what I want it to do. On page load the search box has a green check, while the search is active it has a loading gif, once search is complete it has a green check again.

A sample of what I'm trying to do is here: http://jsbin.com/iqehop/3/

Comment: Your implementation is not using AJAX, and it's searching strictly the dom, why is a loading indicator even necessary here?

Comment: how are you searching, do it with ajax and then on sucess u can remove ur gif image

Comment: Currently I'm using jQuery - TomCoote ColumnFilter plugin. The loading indicator is necessary because it will be applied to a very large table (2500+ rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided the best way for it to do what I want is to modify the plugin with a new setting.

I used the setting mentioned by peterm as a template to add the functionality I wanted.  The resulting jQuery is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#blueprintSelectionTable').columnFilters({wildCard:"", backgroundImg:"true", alternateRowClassNames:['tablerow_odd', 'tablerow_even']});
});
```

A working example is http://jsbin.com/iqehop/8/watch

If anyone comes across this in the future, please don't link the plugin scripts to your pages.  Please download your own copy from http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-column-filters/ and add it to your server.  Or you can copy paste the js file I have linked in my example to your own js file and upload it to your server, just be sure to modify the `var backgroundImgLoc = 'url to image';` on line 48 to your own image.  All other background-image settings are handled by css so the workload is minimized for jQuery.

```
._filterText {
    background:url('../img/tick.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
}
```

Comment: You might consider to propose the changes to the plugin author

Answer (score 2):

That plugin has a setting `underline` to show that filtering is in progress. According to the author:

> ...
>   **underline** :   Set to true if the script is to underline the search text
>   whilst filtering is in progress... good for tables with lots of rows
>   where the filter may take a second. (not in Opera)
>   ...

```
$('#demoTable').columnFilters({wildCard:"", underline:"true", alternateRowClassNames:['tablerow_odd', 'tablerow_even']});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I don't think a simple underline is sufficient but that at least gives my a direction to work with.

Comment: If it's not sufficient you can achieve your goal quick and dirty way changing a few lines of code in the plugin, particularly where css for underline is applied        `if (settings.underline) {     $(filterBox).css('text-decoration','underline');
}` and `if (settings.underline) {       $(this).css('text-decoration','');
}`